# Java DateFormat: most convenient & elegant way to validate input date against multiple patterns

Tags: java

I'm doing like that now:

```
......

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
try{
    dateFormat.parse(criteria.getPeriodFrom());
    dateFormat.parse(criteria.getPeriodTo());
}
catch{
    errors.reject("Incorrect format");
}

......
```

But what if I need to validate against few acceptable patterns (ex. "dd.MM.yyyy", "ddMMyyyy" ....). And I don't want to do any copy&paste or iterate through collection of DateFormats :) Are there cool libraries for that?

Comment: I dont know if this will help, but check out JodaTime at http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the loop *outside* the try/catch block:

```
boolean success = false;
for (DateFormat candidate : formats) {
    try {
        candidate.parse(criteria.getPeriodFrom());
        candidate.parse(criteria.getPeriodTo());
        success = true;
        break;
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        // Expected... move on
    }
}
if (!success) {
    errors.reject("Incorrect format");
}
```

Unforunately neither the Java built-in libraries nor the normally-excellent [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) have anything like .NET's `DateTime.TryParseExact` which lets you *test* whether a parse operation works, without the ugly exception :( Mind you, at least Joda Time's formatters are thread-safe and immutable.

EDIT: I may be wrong... apparently [`DateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29) just returns null on failure, so you could use:

```
for (DateFormat candidate : formats) {
    if (isValid(candidate, criteria)) {
        // whatever
    }
}

...
private static boolean isValid(DateFormat format, Criteria criteria) {
    return format.parse(criteria.getPeriodFrom(), new ParsePosition(0)) != null &&
           format.parse(criteria.getPeriodTo(), new ParsePosition(0)) != null))
}
```

Comment: This is the only way I've seen it done using the plain Java library. FYI, your for statement should probably be `for(DateFormat dateFormat : formats){...}`

Comment: @JavaDrinker: See my edit - I think there's a nicer way... see my edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet you used `DateFormat candidate` then called your function with `dateFormat`

Comment: @Mike: Whoops, thanks - I fixed it in the first bit of code, but not the second...